# How to get a count of *non-minimized* windows in the current Space?

Tags: applescript

I can get a count of Firefox windows in the current Space, including any minimized windows (from any Space - what odd semantics) using something like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    count of windows of process "Firefox"
end tell
```

... and I can get a count of *any* minimized windows (from any application/space) with this:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
    count (UI elements of list 1 where role description is "minimized window dock item")
end tell
```

I cannot, however, figure out how to assemble a count of:

1. *non-minimized* windows,
2. for a *specific* application,
3. on the current Space.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out shortly after posting, because of course I did (thanks, [Script Debugger](https://latenightsw.com/) — what a cool find):

```
tell application "System Events"
    count (windows of process "Firefox" where value of attribute "AXMinimized" is true)
end tell
```